Replacing inline rotary lamp switch
I'm replacing a rotary inline lamp switch. I found a replacement one to buy that matches the amps and gauge of the old one, but has 125 VAC instead of 120 VAC. Is that okay?

Voltage is usually given a range.  The standard now is ~120v, but most electrical devices can handle at least 110 to 130v with no problem.  The main thing is it to have a UL/ELT/CSA label stating it is safe to use.

Yes, that is fine. First of all, higher voltage rating is always OK in a replacement of this type of item. For example, there are some items which will be rated at 250V but routinely used in 120V replacements.
But specific to this situation is the gradual (over the past century) increase in US standard voltages from 100V/200V to 110V/220V to 120V/240V to 125V/250V. (The two numbers are for hot/neutral and hot/hot in the usual US system). Most places currently have 120V/240V as the utility supplied power, but equipment is designed to handle up to 125V/250V. In fact, many devices are rated with a slightly larger range to allow for things like 127V in Mexico.
So 120V -> 125V is (a) normal and (b) fine.

Voltage is a rating for how much voltage it can safely take.
In your case the higher rating is better, it means it can safely handle higher voltage.
Voltage rating is insulation dependent, so better insulation equals higher voltage protection.

Yes, voltage is insulation dependent. But when it comes to switches there are other concerns as well.
